# Boolean comparison in rspec error

Tags: ruby, rspec2

In Rspec, I'm trying to test the approximative return value of a function.

I defined the following :

```
def approx_equals(val, expected, perc_error_accepted)
    margin = (expected * perc_error_accepted / 100)
    return val >= expected - margin && val <= expected + margin
end
```

and now I want to test my function in this way :

```
describe Foo do
  context "comparing return values" do
    expect(approx_equals(obj.datas[:bar], 500, 10)).to eq(true)
  end
end
```

But I got the following error : `undefined method 'expect' for #<Class:0x3cf5340> (NoMethodError)`

I tried the following too :

```
describe Foo do
  context "comparing return values" do
    approx_equals(obj.datas[:bar], 500, 10).should == true
  end
end
```

But rspec stopped its execution in case of a fail so that was not a good solution for me.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`context` in `RSpec` are not tests, they are just aliases for `describe`. Place your code inside an `it` block and It will work.

```
describe Foo do
  it "compares return values" do
    expect(approx_equals(obj.datas[:bar], 500, 10)).to eq(true)
  end
end
```

**EDIT**

Also, you should use RSpec matchers like so:

`expect(approx_equals(obj.datas[:bar], 500, 10)).to be_true`

It will give you a nicer output on failure.

On RSpec3 the matcher was changed from `be_true` to `be true`

Comment: The correct syntax is now `expect(actual).to be true` ([source](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations))

Comment: @Spone The question was tagged and was in question of RSpec 2. Updated response to show the change that was done on RSpec 3.

Answer (score 1):

Your tests should be inside an `it {}` block. ie:

```
describe Foo do
    context "comparing return values" do
        it { approx_equals(obj.datas[:bar], 500, 10).should == true }
    end
end
```

More info available at the [project docs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/docs/gettingstarted)

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna do something as be_boolean I think the way is to add rspec_boolean to your Gemfile in the group :development, :test:

gem 'rspec_boolean'

And than your can use be_boolean in your tests

Example: 
expect(val.is_done?).to be_boolean